# Servlet mapping - 2

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have two servlets A and B. And I've made two mappings for them: "/" and "/*". For come reason any URL is rendered by servlet A.

How can I implement the following mapping in Tomcat?

```
/ -> A
/abc -> B
/xyz -> B
```

Comment: Show us the servlet and mapping definitions (XML or @annotation).

Comment: @Andreas, @WebServlet("/") and @WebServlet("/*")

Comment: did u try to change order ? the first match hit ...

Comment: @chenchuk Yes, I tried. There is no effect

Comment: Try inputing nothing in mapping for `A` (just "") and `/` in mapping for `B`.

Comment: @Whatzs, it works, but why?